# .Net library for sending trackbacks

Tags: .net, trackback, pingback

Is there a library for sending trackbacks or pingbacks in .Net? I know the code is not that hard to write, but if someone wrote, debugged it and maintains it, I'd rather re-use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to implement pingback instead of trackback. It took me a fraction of the time to do it (while I never finished trackback). And actually, not many blogs are accepting trackbacks anymore, but they are accepting pingbacks.